# ASP Validators not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, postback, requiredfieldvalidator

I feel embarrassed to be posting this as I'm pretty sure I'm missing something really simple, and this certainly isn't the first time I've used asp validators. I have the following validator controls:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTitle" EnableClientScript="false" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="groupUpdateAL" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAbbr" EnableClientScript="false" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="groupUpdateAL" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlColour" EnableClientScript="false" ValidationGroup="groupUpdateAL" ErrorMessage="*" />

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="groupUpdateAL" CausesValidation="true" /><br />
```

For some reason, if leaving the controls empty I am given the following error:

```
Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
```

It seems the validation controls aren't catching an invalid input.

**What I've Tried:**

I suspected it may have been client validation intercepting the postback, which is why you can see EnableClientScript is set to false now. Didn't work.

Comment: Can you please post the code for the onclick event of your btnSave ?

Comment: The click event handler only makes one call to a method to save what is in the form, is this still of relevance?

Comment: Well, I suppose you're testing the validity in it then ? If(Page.IsValid){...}

Comment: No, that's the idea of these OOTB validation controls, to do all that checking for me and mark the fields with relevant error messages. This works on another page in my solution.

Comment: mmmh I would need to test but I would say without this, your Validator will indeed be set to false, but your action on click will fire anyway if you don't test the validator status...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try testing page validity in the onclick event of your btnSave :

```
if(Page.IsValid)
{
    //Do your stuff
}
else
{
    Response.Write("error");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, but this is reinventing the wheel that the validation control already deals with.

Comment: No, you still have to check validity server side : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx

Comment: My apologies, I was wrong. And your solution worked. Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score -1):

Validation is on new screen 
in c# file  avalilabel on this image plzz click
on this image 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5R6I.png)

Comment: Please include the image here.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

1. Create database to get querystring
2. Create connection file in visual studio

   [image]

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include your code as text instead of a picture of the code.